# Divisibility test for a random number n

Tags: number-theory

If a number n has 60 divisors and 7n has 80 divisors, what is the greatest power of 7 that divides  n.
a)1 b)2 C)3 d)4

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle n=7^a\cdot\prod p_i^{r_i}$ where integer $a\ge0$ and $p_i$s are distinct primes and integer $r_i$s$>0$

So, the number of divisors of $n$ is $\displaystyle(a+1)\prod(r_i+1)=60\ \ \ \ (1)$

So, the number of divisors of $7n$ will be $\displaystyle(a+1+1)\prod(r_i+1)=80\ \ \ \ (2)$

Divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ to find $a$

Comment: Reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function